# Stored Procedures and Datasets

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a stored procedure that returns multiple tables for a data set

```
Select * from [Users];
Select * from [Supplier];
....
```

Using .net I can put this into a `Dataset`, but I don't get any of the table names:

```
Dim ds As DataSet = SQL.Get_dataSet("EXEC  [Stored_Procedure_Name]")
Dim i As Integer = 0

Do Until i = ds.Tables.Count
   msgbox(ds.Tables(d).TableName)
   d = d + 1
Loop
```

This returns generic names: Table1,table2,table3  instead of [Users],[Supplier],[...]

My `Get_DataSet` function is as follows:

```
Shared Function SQLdataSet(query As String) As DataSet

Dim TempTable As New DataSet
Dim Tempdata As SqlDataAdapter

Using SQLConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(Connection_String_Current)
    SQLConnection.Open()

    Tempdata = New SqlDataAdapter(query, SQLConnection)
    Tempdata.Fill(TempTable)
End Using

Return TempTable

End Function
```

Comment: and what does method Get_dataSet() do ???

Comment: It appears like you are using a custom data layer bc Get_dataSet is not a method of SqlClient or any standard .NET database library that I know of. That being said, this is the default data adapter behavior when you have one proc that returns multiple result sets. If you were using the SqlClient libraries you could specify the "main" table name, and then it would automatically increment the table # as additional result sets were returned.

Comment: its a custom function i wrote to fill a dataset from a SQLdataAdapter

Comment: i'll add my function now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears like you are using a custom data layer bc Get_dataSet is not a method of SqlClient or any standard .NET database library that I know of. That being said, this is the default data adapter behavior when you have one proc that returns multiple result sets. If you were using the SqlClient libraries you could specify the "main" table name, and then it would still automatically increment that "main" table # as additional result sets were returned

Comment: so there is no way of getting the actual Table name?

Comment: @Frank_Vr: SQL Server returns column names but not the table name. In the general case, it can't -- the SELECT might join multiple tables; what table name should it return then?

Comment: as per the both example, it should return, Users and Supplier as the table names

Comment: .NET does not know the tables that are related to every result set. Take an ad hoc query that joins 10 tables together, what table name should the data adapter give to that query? The option exists in an override for the data adapter fill method to supply your own table name. Then you would need a separate query for each table. Or you could just rely on knowing that table1 = users and table2 = suppliers in your code, and could even declare table variables to help make the code more clear. Ex: dim usersTable as DataTable = ds.Tables(0), suppliersTable as DataTable = ds.Tables(1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [TableMappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.tablemappings.aspx) to map the table names.  E.g. something like (untested):

```
Tempdata = New SqlDataAdapter(query, SQLConnection)
Tempdata.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Users");
Tempdata.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "Supplier");
Tempdata.TableMappings.Add("Table2", "MyTable");
...
Tempdata.Fill(TempTable)
```

IIRC the default table names are `Table,Table1,Table2,...` rather than `Table1,Table2,Table3,...`.

You are required to "know" the table names you expect; they won't be included in the result returned by SQL Server so you can't infer them automatically.